# create local variable in calling function, from a string

Tags: php

I want to be able to call a function, that will set one or more local variables in the calling function.  For instance:

```
function someFunc () {
 loadTranslatedStrings($LOCALS, "spanish");
 echo $hello; // prints "hola";
 }

function loadTranslatedStrings (&$callerLocals, $lang) {
 if ($lang == 'spanish')
   $callerLocals['hello'] = 'hola';
 else if ($lang == 'french')
   $callerLocals['hello'] = 'bonjour';
 else
   $callerLocals['hello'] = 'hello';
 }
```

(I'm guessing it is impossible to do this, but might as well ask...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this...

```
function someFunc () {
   loadTranslatedStrings($lang, "spanish");
   extract($lang); 
   echo $hello; // prints "hola";
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/jAEMq8oC).

Comment: awesome, thanks.  When it let's me accept an answer, I'll flip a coin between you and Tim.  :)

Comment: I gave him an upvote, of course.   Thanks to both of you, this solves the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I think you could get is by using [extract](http://php.net/extract):

```
function someFunc()
{
   extract(loadStrings('french'));
   echo $hello;
}

function loadStrings($lang)
{
   switch($lang)
   {
      case 'spanish':
         return array('hello' => 'hola');
      case 'french':
         return array('hello' => 'bonjour');
   }
}
```

Comment: 2 seconds! +1 for the same idea as me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `$GLOBALS`: `$GLOBALS['hello'] = 'hola';`

Comment: That won't be local to the function.